# getting p-values for a pairwise correlation (dplyr)

Tags: r, dplyr, correlation, p-value, summarize

I am using the code below to get correlations between my dependent variable and a questionnaire response (for different levels of different conditions).

```
BREAK %>%
    group_by(condition, valence) %>%
    summarize(COR=cor(rt, positive_focused_cognitiveER)) %>%
    ungroup()
```

It gives me the correlations and their directions (+/-).
I would like to know, however, if those correlations are significant.
Is there a way to simply add a line to the code I already have to get the p-values? 
Or another easy code? (I don't need fancy stuff, just the numbers)

The only fitting post I found for my problem was this one [Getting p values for groupwise correlation using the dplyr package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47916129/getting-p-values-for-groupwise-correlation-using-the-dplyr-package) but the answer did not help me.

Thanks in advance for any tips! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute p-values with `stats::cor.test` :

```r
BREAK %>%
        group_by(condition, valence) %>%
        summarize(COR = stats::cor.test(rt, positive_focused_cognitiveER)$estimate,
                  pval = stats::cor.test(rt, positive_focused_cognitiveER)$p.value
                  ) %>%
        ungroup()
```

Comment: You could even extract a confidence interval, it is all documented in `?cor.test`

Comment: ah nice, my supervisor would like that I think haha. I'll have a look!